# android app doesn't send or receive audio using phono

Tags: android, sip, audio-streaming, phono

I am developing an app which will use the **phono sdk** for real-time communication between android phones and/or a website.

Now, in the **phono** website it said that the sdk is compatible with android versions 2.0 and above.

The code that is on the website and android is the same, and website to website communication works perfectly.

But when i tried to do website-android communication, no sound could be heard on my tablet(version 4.2.2).

However, when I lauched my program in a 4.4.2 smartphone, the communication was perfect and fully functional.

I have searched all over the web but the documentation of phono is very little.
Any ideas?

I have this in my manifest:

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    try {
        // Java reflection to gain access to TelephonyManager's
        // ITelephony getter
        Log.v("TAG", "Get getTeleService...");
        Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        m.invoke(tm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("TAG","FATAL ERROR: could not connect to telephony subsystem");
        Log.e("TAG","Exception object: " + e);
    }
```

Check if your phone is getting acess or not

Comment: I have inserted this in my code and it connects to the telephony correctly but still no sound....